# Compare date column value to system clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a data-table with a particular column called "scheduled time" that has is using the "Time" variable. I would like to know what's the easiest way to compare the scheduled time in the table to the system time, and in return change the background colour of the row.

My code so far

```
var currentTime = new Date(); /* not sure if this is the correct time object to use */
var scheduledTime = scheduledTime();

if (scheduledTime >= 15mins) {
  return 'background-color:red;'
} else if (scheduledTime > 15mins <= 30mins) {
  return 'background-color:yellow;'
} else if (scheduledTime > 30mins <= 2hours) {
  return 'background-color:green;'
} else if (scheduledTime > 2hours) {
  return 'background-color:none;
}
```

Comment: well your first if would be wrong, it would have to be `<`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
// Assuming scheduledTime()'s output is a "ms since epoch" timestamp.
var scheduledTime = scheduledTime();
var diff = (scheduledTime - currentTime) / 1000 / 60; // Difference in minutes.

return (diff < 15) /*if(d<15) */ ? 'background-color:red;'
     : (diff < 30  && diff > 15) ? 'background-color:yellow;'
     : (diff < 120 && diff > 30) ? 'background-color:green;'
     : /* else */                  'background-color:none;';
```

I'm using a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#JavaScript) as shorthand for a normal `if/else`-block, there.

Comment: I didn't even think to use the difference in minutes method. The ternary operator is much cleaner way of writing this script agreed.I appreciate your time.

Comment: Cebrus, I didnt mentioned that I need this script running on a 24hour clock, would that make any difference in the comparison

Comment: @crh313: It shouldn't since we're comparing timestamps (Miliseconds since January 1st, 1970)